# TFS: Cannot undo or commit changes

Tags: tfs

When I click any node in the source control explorer, the contextual shows the option to undo or check in pending changes.

[image]

When I select either to check in or to undo changes, I'm getting a popup saying that there is no pending changes.

[image]

This situation is preventing me to add a new workspage.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you have any pending changes to check in?  Also, is it possible you're in a different workspace than you think you are?

Comment: Also, check for conflicts. I had this very same issue. I shelved my changes, then got the latest and merged my changes back. if you haven't tried already, disconnect from TFS and close your solution and try reconnecting.

Answer (score 1):

Even though **there are no pending changes at all.** Right click a folder or a file in solution explorer, the `undo pending changes` and `checking in pending changes` will **still be black not gray.**

So first, please make sure you have pending changes for the node first. You can use [tf status command](https://www.visualstudio.com/sl-si/docs/tfvc/status-command) to **display information about pending changes** to files and folders in one or more workspaces.

*List all changes in the current workspace*

```
c:\code\SiteApp\Main\SolutionA\>tf stat
```